# How UIWebvew like Mobile Safari's private mode, can I operate?

Tags: uiwebview, safari, private

How UIWebvew like Mobile Safari's private mode, can I operate?

I've read the search page of Google and Apple's documentation

then,

1. I not found history clear for UIWebview.
2. I Tried delete cookie and remove cache. but it was not operation.